# Want to do an action if a table value equals expected if no perform another action e.g clear fields

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am fairly new to Selenium and am self teaching, I have used a little JAVA years ago

I want to add a statement around value1 to perform an action if value is as expected and perform a different action if not

```
driver.findElement(By.id("task-table-filter")).sendKeys("test1");
        WebElement firstName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"task-table\"]/tbody/tr[8]/td"));
        String value = firstName.getText();
        System.out.println(value);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"task-table-filter\"]")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("task-table-filter")).sendKeys("test2");

    WebElement searchname = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"task-table\"]/tbody/tr[6]/td[3]"));
    String value1 = searchname.getText();
    System.out.println(value1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple if/else

```
if (value1.equals("expected value")) {
    do.action;
} else {
    do.otherActon;
}
```